# How to set user attribute value in Keycloak using API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

How I can set user attribute value using Keycloak Rest API?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

To set a user attribute using the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_authentication_management_resource); you use the endpoint:

```
PUT <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/users/<USER_ID>
```

with the payload

```
{"attributes":{"<ATTRIBUTE_NAME>":["<ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>"]}}
```

the `<USER_ID>` you can get it using the endpoint:

```
GET <YOUR_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/users/?username=<THE_USERNAME>
```

from the `JSON` response, extract the field `id`.

---

**Step-by-Step:**

You can get that information using the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_authentication_management_resource); to call that API, you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. For now, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm:

```bash
curl https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
    -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You will get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To [get the user id](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getusers) from your realm `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X GET https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users/?username=${USERNAME}&exact=true \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

From the response extract the user `id` for example as follows

```
jq -r .[].id
```

Or even cleaner is to passed to the

To [set the user](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_updateuser) attribute:

```bash
curl -X PUT https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users/${USER_ID} \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
     -d '{"attributes":{"<ATTRIBUTE_NAME>":["<ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>"]}}'
```

You can also have a look at [setUser](https://github.com/dreamcrash/Keycloak/blob/main/scripts/setUser) script on my GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful. If, like me you are using a later version of Keycloak (20.0.2) and need to understand how to add the appropriate roles to your properly permissioned admin user, this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075983/keycloak-20-0-2-i-am-not-seeing-the-realm-roles-in-user-role-mapping/75079171

Comment: Also this post about creating the KC admin side of things. And note recent KC versions insist your KC client uses `confidential` autentication and a client secret.
https://medium.hexadefence.com/keycloak-admin-rest-api-63a294814e1b

Comment: Thanks for the links @Murrah, yes whenever possible you should add the additional security layer of having to specify the client secret

Comment: Yes, done. I can now update my KC user's attributes from my Quarkus app. Very cool. 

And just to say the "you" in my comments was for others who might find this - I get you are across all of this! ;-)