# Keycloak 20.0.2: I am not seeing the realm roles in user Role Mapping

Tags: keycloak

When I create a User in my realm, and click the Role Mappings tab, according to every SO post I see there should be a way to select the realm roles to apply. But in my case I am not seeing them.

This is what I see:
[image]

I am trying to add the `manage_users` role, so I can use this User to manage users via the API. But almost all the realm roles are missing from the Role Mapping tab.

Can anyone enlighten me about what else I need to do so the realm roles appear, especially the `realm_management` ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `Role Mappings` tab

[image]

You need to click on the `Assign role` button

[image]

which will popup the following menu:

[image]

and from there you can find the client and realm roles.

> I am trying to add the manage_users role, so I can use this User to
> manage users via the API.

If the previous menu you would change `Filter by realm roles` to `Filter by clients`, and the following menu would show up:

[image]

and in the `Search by role name` field type `realm-management`:

[image]

select `manage_users` and then click `Assign`. You should see that role being assigned to your user

[image]

Comment: I was fighting for hours to do exactly the same thing. Changing the filter was so misleading and I never considered that. Because you'd assume that by default a filter setting would show all available options. I don't think this thing should be called "filter".

Comment: @LarsBlumberg Yep, I also have struggled with the same, I have the feeling that the new UI is a bit less intuitive that the previous. Or maybe I was just used to the old one.

Comment: I am using KeyCloak for the first time, never used pre-21 versions. Yes, the new UI is misleading us here.

Comment: Just spent 30 mins trying to assign a role. Would not have figured it out without this post.